# Not compatible RAM module

Tags: memory

According to the specs of my Fujitsu Esprimo P2560 desktop the maximum RAM is 8 GB. There are 2 slots and currently there are 2+2 GB installed. I tried to upgrade the memory bank by removing one of the 2GB and replace it with a 4 GB module but this did not work. The module in question is a 4 GB 240-pin DDR3 8500 1066 MHz. Exactly the same as the 2 GB. Furthermore, I have the latest BIOS installed. Anyone out there have a clue?

Comment: Does it work by itself, as the only inserted module? I could be outside of some limitations of the mainboard, like number of chips, banks etc...

Comment: Okay, seems to be a chipset issue. Give me a moment...

Comment: The "did not work" statement means that the system did not start after the installation. The only thing that did start was the fan that kept on going until the power was cut. And yes, I have tried using the 4 GB as the only modul.

Answer (score 0):

#### The G41 Express chipset has an obscure limitation which requires the use of dual-rank memory modules, which are typically double-sided, to attain 8 GB of memory.

- Your computer uses the **[G41 Express chipset](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/mainstream-chipsets/g41-express-chipset.html)**. The official Intel specification states that it can only handle 4 GB of DDR3 memory. 8 GB of DDR3 will work but only with a specific configuration. Specifically, the chipset cannot handle modules containing higher-density memory chips.
- This means that compatible 4 GB modules must have two sets, or **[ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_rank)**, of lower-density chips. Dual-rank memory modules are required to enable the use of 8 GB of RAM on your system. These modules are typically double-sided in order to accommodate the extra memory chips.

[image: Double-sided memory module]<sub>*[Image source](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/G41C-GS/)*</sub>

Comment: It seems that the module in question is in fact a dual rank/low density. Please check http://www.mrmemory.co.uk/memory-ram-upgrades/fujitsu-siemens/esprimo/p2560