# Too much hardware reserved memory

Tags: windows-7, boot, memory, motherboard, bios

## Background

My parents have a Gateway lx6810-01 that had 32 bit Windows Vista Home Premium. It has two 4 GB sticks of RAM installed (GSkill F3-10600CL9D-8GBNT), totaling 8 GBs. The RAM came with the machine. The weird thing is that the system says that it had DDR2 RAM, even though it came with DDR3 ([click here for system specs](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883113089)).

Regardless, I looked up the [user manual](http://www.cizgi.com.tr/upload/pms_dosya/198/g41mxe_en.pdf) of the motherboard and it said that the sticks should be compatible.

**Because half the RAM was not addressable, I just installed Windows 7 64 bit Professional.**

## Problem

When I boot up the system I notice in the resource monitor that only about 3 GBs are available, and 5 GBs are under Hardware Reserved Memory. The system still recognizes the 8 GBs of RAM, but only 3 GBs are usable.

## Failed attempted solutions

### Side note

I ran CPU-Z and it recognized all my RAM and it seemed to be normal.

I also thought maybe the resource panel was displaying my amount of RAM available incorrectly, but when I ran a Python script that kept allocating memory, I ran out after about 3 GBs.

1. **msconfig**

   I first tried running `msconfig` and checking **and** unchecking the maximum memory checkbox.
2. **Memory remapping and memory hole in BIOS**

   Memory remapping was already enabled, but memory hole was not in the BIOS. I tried every combination of the two being enabled and disabled, but nothing fixed it.
3. **Memory diagnostic**

   I ran a memory diagnostic in case something was wrong with the memory, but it said everything was fine.
4. **Bootable Ubuntu USB**

   I booted up Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from a USB, to check if the problem was Windows, but the problem still existed.
5. **Rearranged and isolated RAM**

   I switched the stick, but nothing changed.

   I tried booting up with each stick in each slot by itself, but for every combination the resource monitor showed that 1 GB was Hardware Reserved Memory and the other 3 GBs were available. **This makes me think that for some reason the BIOS only recognizes one of the sticks.** But I don't know why.
6. **Manually set RAM speed**

   I manually set RAM speed to 800 MHz instead of 'auto', but I was unable boot up after that, and had to remove my CMOS battery to restore the BIOS to its defaults.
7. **Checked memory allocation for hardware devices**

   I opened up the device manager and checked to see how memory my device were taking up but nothing was out of the ordinary that would take up more than a few hundred MBs.

## The Present

I have no idea what to do anymore. Maybe update the BIOS, but there are not any updates that address this issue.

Comment: look for a BIOS update.

Comment: One more odd way to see things, i only did this one time. In device manager "view by resources" or using "system Info" you can see the actual locked out hard addresses in some alien form :-) well alien to me .  And also device manager bring up the properties for a device (like a video card) and looking at the "resources" tab i was able to locate and somewhat figure what and where the ram spaces used by the device were.

Comment: Thanks @Psycogeek for your comment. The mother board only comes with two slots, and I believe cpu-z was saying that it was in dual configuration. I'll check again later and let you know because Windows 7 is updating right now and I do not want to interrupt it. According to online my cpu specs are [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/36547/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q8200-4M-Cache-2_33-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB). I installed Windows clean with a bootable usb. I've reset the BIOS already. I've never updated my BIOS before, but I could probably do it.

Comment: The problem is that there is not a BIOS update that more recent than my BIOS (6/7/2011) that addresses this issue. [Link to BIOS updates](http://www.foxconnsupport.com/download.aspx?models=&category=C000000001&series=&keywords=G41MXE). I guess there is the possibility that I have an older BIOS. I'll try running memtest86 first and see what it gives me. I thought windows memory diagnostic tool would perform similarly though.

Comment: Also I looked at the device manager "view by resources" already, and it showed the HEX memory address that were allocated, and it was no more than a few hundred MBs.

Comment: @Psycogeek I ran the memtest86 but it only recognized 3 GBs of RAM. I also flashed the BIOS with the most recent version and nothing changed.

Comment: On to the manuel: An important item in the bios here is "Memory Remap Feature" "This item is used to enable/disable memory remap feature. Its mainly for if you have a 64bit OS and 4GB of RAM."  Uhh yea and usually it would be ON when using 8G too. "Memory Hole" item is meaningless for this problem. " IGD Graphics Mode Select" & "DVMT Mode Select"  important for laying out shared video memory and locking shared, but boards of that time would not be locking 5Gig. The G-41 chipset ram chip layout issues http://superuser.com/a/932116/98855  so far I think it is ram compatability problem.

Answer (score 3):

It's not in the OS, you should be able to set the allocated amount to the igpu, it's usually set on auto by default.
Set it in the bios