# What memory do I need for my new CPU?

Tags: memory, cpu

I upgraded my CPU, and it will only run with one of my three different memory sticks. The previous CPU ran with (and loaded) all three sticks. So I guess I have to buy some new sticks(?), however - I'm a bit confused on what to buy since two of the sticks have the same specs, but as stated only one works.

- Works with (Hynix 2GB): http://www.hynix.com/datasheet/eng/module/details/module_20_HMT125U6TFR8C.jsp (Part number H9)
- Does not work with (Kingston 2GB): http://www.electrobyt.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=622#.VpEOclLlnyE
- Does not work with (ADATA 4GB): http://www.wermlandsdata.se/catalog/product_info.php?cPath=632_110_509_706&products_id=193989

I've tried running the new CPU with all sorts of combinations, one by one and different DIMM slots - the only memory that works is the Hynix, and it doesn't matter what DIMM slot I put it in.

The old CPU worked with all 3 simultaneously and one by one.

- Old CPU: (E5500, 2 MB cache, 2.80 GHz): http://ark.intel.com/sv/products/42800/Intel-Pentium-Processor-E5500-2M-Cache-2_80-GHz-800-MHz-FSB
- New CPU: (Q8400, 4 MB cache, 2.66 GHz): http://ark.intel.com/sv/products/38512/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q8400-4M-Cache-2_66-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB
- Computer Model (HP Pro 3120 MT): http://www.manualslib.com/manual/435619/Hp-Pro-3120-Minitower-Pc.html?page=2#manual

I can see how the ADATA memory wouldn't work since it has a different clock frequency than the Hynix, but why does the new CPU run with Hynix but not the Kingston memory? And what kind of memory do I need to buy?

Comment: http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/homepage

Comment: @DavidPostill That doesn't really help me at all - you give me a link to a website that sells various kinds of memory sticks, and I need to know what specific kind of memory I need - not where I could buy one.

Comment: Look again "Download and use our scanner tool, which will analyze your system's hardware and **provide a list of compatible upgrades that will work best with your system's specs and capabilities.**" This will analyse your machine and tell you what is compatible with your motherboard and new CPU.

Comment: @DavidPostill this is the result: http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/scanview/626FB9C831D926C3

Would either of these be equivalent:

http://www.webhallen.com/se-sv/datorkomponenter/115177-corsair_xms3_4gb_ddr3_pc3-10600_1333mhz or

http://www.webhallen.com/se-sv/datorkomponenter/127263-corsair_valueselect_4_gb_ddr3_pc3-10600_1333mhz

Comment: @DavidPostill or could it be that I can't exceed 2gb per dimm with the new cpu?

Comment: @Moab Sorry about that, I've updated the topic with: Computer Model (HP Pro 3120 MT): www.manualslib.com/manual/435619/Hp-Pro-3120-Minitower-Pc.html?page=2#manual

Comment: Is it the case where one module is double-sided but the others are single-sided? Your system has the G43 chipset, which shouldn't be subject to the "four ranks per channel" limitation but just putting this out there just in case: http://superuser.com/questions/932107/not-compatible-ram-module

Comment: @bwDraco The Hynix and the ADATA sticks are double-sided, the Kingston is single-sided.

Comment: @DavidPostill The memory that crucial recommends have such different specs from the actual memory that does work, PC3-12800 vs PC3-10600, 1.35V vs 1.5V, 1600 MHz vs 1333 MHz. Could this really be the memory that I need...?

Comment: @eskilla Sorry, no idea.

Answer (score 0):

#### The memory controller doesn't appear to support high-density modules with more than 1 GB per rank with the processor installed on your system.

- The 2 GB Hynix module is a [dual-rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_rank) (double-sided) module. This means that each rank has 1 GB of memory. However, the other modules you tested (Kingston 2 GB single-rank, ADATA 4 GB dual-rank) have 2 GB per rank.
- The memory controller on the system does not appear to support modules with more than 1 GB per memory rank with the Q8400 installed. As such, modules larger than 2 GB and single-rank (single-sided) 2 GB modules will not work on your system. It is not clear why this is happening with the new CPU only; there might be a compatibility issue with the processor and chipset.